# I check all the forum but not find a solution | "Open external links of my webview in browser and not in app" does not work

Tags: android, android-studio, webview, android-webview

thanks for read my question :) I am not able to solve this problem after check all the forum. I am working on my first webview. Nothing special. It's a webview with progress bar. My code in "shouldOverrideUrlLoading" method is not working. I want that all external links of my site open in browser and not in app, but it does not work. Can anyone please check my code?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

private WebView wv;
private ProgressBar progressBar;
private FrameLayout frameLayout;
SwipeRefreshLayout swipe;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    frameLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.frameLayout);
    progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    progressBar.setMax(100);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    swipe = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipe);
    swipe.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            String webUrl = wv.getUrl();
            wv.loadUrl(webUrl);
        }
    });
    LoadWeb();

}

public void LoadWeb(){

    wv = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
    WebSettings settings = wv.getSettings();
    settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    wv.loadUrl("example.com");
    swipe.setRefreshing(true);
    wv.setWebViewClient(new HelpClient());
    wv.setWebViewClient(new MyAppWebViewClient());

    wv.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient(){
        public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress){
            frameLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            progressBar.setProgress(progress);

            if (progress == 100){
                frameLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            }
            super.onProgressChanged(view, progress);
        }
    });
    progressBar.setProgress(0);

    wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){

        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url){
            swipe.setRefreshing(false);
        }
    });

}

private class HelpClient extends WebViewClient {

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url){
        view.loadUrl(url);
        frameLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        return true;

    }
}

private class MyAppWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

        if(Uri.parse(url).getHost().endsWith("example.com")) {
            return false;
        }
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
        view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
        return true;
    }

}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if(wv.canGoBack()) {
        wv.goBack();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement


    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_home) {
        wv.loadUrl("example.com");

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_facebook) {

        try {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("fb://page/idfbpage"));
            startActivity(intent);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Intent intent =  new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://www.facebook.com/idfbpage"));
            startActivity(intent);
        }

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_instagram) {

        Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://instagram.com/_u/idinstapage");
        Intent likeIng = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
        likeIng.setPackage("com.instagram.android");

        try {
            startActivity(likeIng);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://instagram.com/idinstapage")));
        }

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_star) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id=idpackage"));
        startActivity(intent);

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_informazioni) {
        wv.loadUrl("example.com/info-app");

    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
 }

}
```

Comment: did you try debugging it ? does that code execute ?

Comment: Yes. It execute without errors. Thanks for answer :)

Comment: why are you using two instances of WebViewClient ?

Comment: Is it wrong? The instance "HelpClient" is for the progressbar.

Comment: yes ,it is , look carefully you are overrinfing same method twice with defferent outcomes , just use the later one MyAppWebClient

Comment: Ah ok. Thanks. So i should remove "wv.setWebViewClient(new HelpClient());" ?
And what about "private class HelpClient extends WebViewClient {..}" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your method `LoadWeb()` there is an error because your `WebView` should have only one `WebViewClient` and only one `WebChromeClient`. So what happens is, if you use the method `wv.setWebViewClient(new YourWebViewClient());` more than once what happens is that all other methods set before that are ignored because you can set it only once.
**For your case:**
You set the `WebViewClient` Three (3) times:

```
wv.setWebViewClient(new HelpClient());   //First time
wv.setWebViewClient(new MyAppWebViewClient());  //Second time
```

And the last time you set it down in your same method you set another like:

```
wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){

    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url){
        swipe.setRefreshing(false);
    }
});
```

So what happens is that the two previous methods were ignored and the only method that was working was the last one (the third) only. *That's why I asked you to put the second method down to `setWebClient((new MyAppWebViewClient());` so as to ignore the previous!*

**THE SOLUTION**
Now you know we have to set only one `WebViewClient` for your `webView` we have to make only **ONE** Class that will be used to and do the job of all three other `WebViewClient` by overriding all the required methods. Make this class inside your activity but oustide your any method (*just like how you have done when making in HelpClient() Class*). Here is Our Class Please make sure you read the Comments in it!

```
private class NewWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
       //Now we have only one class to do a job of all the other three!

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        /*I here do whatever you want to do when the page has finished loading! Do it here inside this method and it will work may be control the framelayout visibility For example lets setRefreshing false to our swipe()*/
        swipe.setRefreshing(false);
        //.....add more methods you want here when the page loading is finished
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        /*In this method we are going to tell the android system what kind of link we want and what kind of link we dont want for that what we want we will handle for the extra the browser should do so!*/
        if (Uri.parse(url).getHost().endsWith("example.com")) {
            //if the code gets here this is your link then right? Lets do whatever we want with our link and logic for example lets set framelayout visible or doing anything this link's host is example.com!
            frameLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            return false;
        } else {
            //Ooops This link is not yours lets just open browsers right 
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
            view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        }

    }

}
```

After your class is beautiful then lets just set our `WebViewClient` only **ONCE**.

```
wv.setWebViewClient(new NewWebViewClient());
```

You can just ignore the `WebChromeClient` because you set it only once you are good. Comment below if you find any difficulties!

Comment: Hi Xenolion :) Thanks for your answer <3 I tried and now it works, I am able to open external link in browser, but the "swipe" to reload the current url does not work. How is it possibile ?? I am so confused !! It's a problem with all the swipe codes...

Comment: Okay I knew you will come back for that so lets work this out! Accept my answer as correct by putting a tick. I am writting the code for you to improve your code as I promised. I will show a logic error of what happened just wait 4 minutes dont go offline!

Comment: Yeah sure. Your answer is the best! Wow dude, I can't thank you enough for helping me :)

Comment: Sorry I am taking so long! I have found one of your methods was deprecated so I am checking for the new one!

Comment: I am here ahah I can wait for you also for 987987 hours if necessary ahah

Comment: Finished! Check the edited solution! Any other problem just Comment!

Comment: Have finished just read the solution carefully you will get it. Sorry I made you wait

Comment: I think that every day we have the possibility to meet special person... And it's what happened to me today :) AMAZING, it works perfectly! Your explanation was so clear. I have no words, only thank u, thank u and thank u :) Now I understand everything, wow... You let me shocked ahah Really man, thanks :D

Comment: YEAH debugging might be a challenge especially when its not a syntax error. I am glad I met you too! All the best in your coding life! **Happy Coding!**

Comment: Hi @Xenolion , how are you ? I need to ask you something, could you give me an email to contact you ? Thanks bro <3

Comment: Sorry I was not online today my email is `johnnnoni@gmail.com` !!

Answer (score 0):

I hope removing the this line

```
wv.setWebViewClient(new MyAppWebViewClient());
```

will solve the problem for you.

Comment: Just tried. Nothing. It open all the link in the app. Instead, i would like to open only internal link in the app.

Answer (score 0):

You are using two instances of WebViewClient ,remove one ,

```
private class MyAppWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    Log.d("TAG",url);
    if(Uri.parse(url).getHost().equals("example.com")) {
        return false;
    }
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
    view.getContext().startActivity(intent);//add the brakpoint here
    Log.d("TAG","Starting activity");
    return true;
}
```

}

just use this

Comment: Are you sure that the problem?

Comment: Just tried. I remove  "wv.setWebViewClient(new HelpClient());" and "private class HelpClient extends WebViewClient {..}". Nothing. It still open all link in the app. I will be crazy ahah :'(

Comment: print the url , place a log cat before the return true, also select a breakpoint there and debug it again.

Comment: May you please write me how to do? I am still not able 

Comment: Tried. Nothing :'(